# When random output is a local maximum, how can a neural network find the global (or a better local) maximum?

Tags: neural-networks, randomness

I'm trying to train a neural network to play Rock-Paper-Scissors.  A random player is a local maximum for the game, as it wins 50% of the time. In a tournament setting, it comes out consistently better than the worst bots and consistently worse than the better bots.

Against the very worst bots, my neural networks have found solutions that win 95%+ of the time.  Against anything else, my neural networks quickly turn into random-ish players.  They stay stuck at that local maximum and never find better strategies.

Based on my naive experiments, it seems that, from any given starting point, there are many nearby weight combinations which will generate random-ish output from moderately complex input.  In most applications, this isn't a problem because random output scores poorly and gradient descent slides right past those weight combinations.  But in Rock-Paper-Scissors, all of those random-ish generating weight combinations - and there seem to be a lot of them, many magnitudes more than the number of weight combinations which produce more sophisticated strategies - act as attractors for gradient descent.

Are there any known solutions to this problem or heuristics which might address it?  When random-ish output from moderately complex input is a reasonably good solution, can neural networks be set up or trained in a way which consistently finds better solutions?

Or is Rock-Paper-Scissors too hard for neural nets?

Edit: I'm specifically trying to achieve blank-slate learning-via-playing, rather than training it on an existing corpus of moves.  From my research so far, though, it looks like bots in other games which learn via playing learn most effectively when they explore the move space in a more purposeful way, effectively building a corpus of moves to train from.

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve. It seems like the optimal strategy for RPS is to choose R, P or S at random. What's the objective function? How do you possibly collect data?

Comment: @Sycorax: There's a good explanation [here](https://daniel.lawrence.lu/programming/rps/).  "Suppose you have 10 opponents, of which 9 play randomly and 1 always plays rock. If you also play randomly, you’ll win 50% of the time. If you always play paper, however, you will win 55% of the time, since you’ll always beat the guy that always plays rock, while still faring the same against the random players. A win rate of 55% is better than a win rate of 50%. Importantly, as long as there is even a single non-random player in the pool, an algorithm that exploits the patterns will always do better."

Comment: @Sycorax: The neural networks I've created are able to figure out and beat "rock-rock-rock", rotation, and frequency-counting opponents, giving them a [win rate](http://www.rpscontest.com/authorSearch?name=clawsoon) of about 70%.  However, they're not able to figure out the history-matching opponents, and instead devolve to playing randomly.  That's not a bad strategy, but it's not as good as [the best](http://www.rpscontest.com/leaderboard) bots, which can defeat history-matching (and also use [Iocaine Powder](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~darse/rsb-ts1.c)-style metastrategies).

Comment: This still seems strange. Are you familiar with Nash equilibrium?

Comment: @Sycorax: I've bumped into it in various game theory contexts.  I suspect that it doesn't apply in this case because losers are not eliminated from the tournament.  Since some players - the losers who don't get eliminated - are not playing equilibrium strategies, a player who wants to win the tournament has to play to win against weaker players rather than playing the equilibrium strategy.  That's part of what makes this an interesting problem.

Comment: Well, the assumption of that variety of game theory equilibrium is that it assumes **both** parties are attempting to attain optimal strategies. The "all rock" strategy clearly violates that assumption.

Comment: For these kinds of interactive problems, a prominent and "hot" area of research is so-called [tag:Q-learning] or [tag:reinforcement-learning]. I don't know much of anything about it, but this seems very relevant to your problem. You may have seen it in the context of computers learning to play Atari games.

Comment: I bumped into reinforcement learning in my earlier investigation, but didn't have time to look into it.  I understand that it was also part of the AlphaZero approach. Might be time to look into it again, once I have time to return to this problem.  Thanks for the discussion!